How does a closed-cycle rocket engine keep the chamber pressure from stalling the pump turbine?
I was thinking about how a closed-cycle rocket engine works, and I have a question about how the turbine can keep running.

As I understand it, once the engine is up and running, the pressure in the combustion chamber creates back-pressure on the fuel and oxidizer lines, which the pumps have to overcome to force reactants into the chamber. In an open-cycle, this is provided by a preburner that runs a gas turbine and then dumps the partially burned exhaust overboard (into an environment that's, at most, at 1 atmosphere of pressure).
But for a closed-cycle, the fuel goes from the pump through the preburner, through the gas turbine that powers the pumps, and then into the chamber against all that back-pressure. So doesn't that put the whole pump system into a sort of "by your own bootstraps" situation? You have to spin the turbine to turn the pump to spin the turbine.

In operation, all forces are balanced. The "by your own bootstraps" situation you're describing occurs at startup, where things can get really tricky. In between are transients (oscillations) due to the coupling. These must be damped by whatever mechanism (usually just drag on the shaft or fluid).
Startup is hard. There are usually separate systems to get the turbine spinning. Could be high pressure gas; some other pressure fed feed system; a solid starter...

@AntonHengst If the forces were balanced in operation, then nothing would go anywhere. The pump has to push harder than the back-pressure, which is the source of my question!

No, it doesn't--if it were pushing harder, the pump would continue to revolve more quickly. In steady state (a joke due to turbulence, but for some time-averaged definition of the concept...) the pump is pushing as hard on a unit volume of fluid as the unit volume is pushing back. In an eularian sense, each particle of fluid is still being net accelerated eventually towards the outlet (& microscopically as T & P rise), but in an lagrangian sense the forces are balanced

At least in the Space Shuttle Main Engine, the high-pressure pump turbines didn't stall because the preburners operated at much, much higher pressure than the main combustion chamber.
The preburners were at ~5000 psi (~35 MPa) while the main combustion chamber was at "only" ~3000 psi (~21 MPa).

Source: http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf (highlighting mine)
The "bootstrap" situation you describe mainly was a factor in starting the engine. I don't know if this is the focus of your question so I won't go into too much detail, but the start sequence was a highly choreographed open-loop affair. The relevant parts here are the order in which the three combustion chambers primed and then ignited, initially driven by pressure from the External Tank. If this is of interest to you, there is a fabulous writeup on how it all worked in the paper "Reusable Rocket Engine Intelligent Control System" section 5.1 "The Current SSME Startup Sequence".

I think the fact that the preburner is running a frankly just absurd pressure is the answer to my question. I'm still having a hard time envisioning the way the forces are all working to make it happen, but I'll accept that it's just hard for me to see it.

@DarthPseudonym and check out the outlet pressure of the O2 booster pump at the bottom of the right hand side...almost 7000 psi, to pump the O2 through the control valves and into the preburners!

I object to the inclusion of metric units in this OrganicMarble answer. Clearly this is a deepfake.  (units have been on my mind, I saw BTU/ft^2/sec in some Orion sim-or-adjacent code this week)

@ErinAnne lol, I just hope the conversion is correct.

@OrganicMarble I recommend Qalculate! an excellent calculator with support for units. Your conversion checks out, but being pedantic the 5000 psi would round down to 34 MPa - just. Just to get Darth Pseudonyms absurd pressures right: common rail direct fuel injection in car engines work at up to 36000 psi (2500 bar or 250 MPa). But the amount of mass moving in these rocket engines is incredible.

It never fails to amaze me the nitty gritty details and depth and breadth of NASA knowledge that @OrganicMarble willingly shares!  Thanks for helping us all be much more informed!

I think I understand your bootstrap question and it doesn't seem like anyone else has directly addressed it so I'll give it a try. Another way to put your question is "how can a pump generate a high pressure when the turbine is driven by the same fluid it's pumping.
And the answer is, of course, combustion. But we think of combustion as generating high pressures, so doesn't that generate back pressure against the pump which makes it stop working?
No, it doesn't. What happens is combustion in the preburner increases the temperature of combustion gas but this translates into a greater volume of exhaust gas because the cross sectional area of the exhaust manifold is larger than the cross sectional area of the inlet manifolds so the pressure in the preburner is still lower than the pump. The energy of the preburner exhaust is quite high and some of it is captured by the turbine to turn the pump.
